# How can I efficiently set up wordpress and AWS Amplify together?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, aws-amplify

**I have the need to have a project made up of two parts, the use case seems relatively typical:**

- An AWS Amplify react project, which has some API endpoints and a nice dashboard written in react.
- A wordpress website with a blog, maintained by someone not very technical.

The reason for this separation is that the owner of the company is familiar with wordpress and would like to manage SEO as well as regularly writing blog posts. The main companies purpose (The SaaS) is the amplify project. There is a high probability that the owner will install lots of plugins on the wordpress site, and may well cause it to go down, in this case the amplify project must remain functional.

**Ideally:**

- `example.com` -> Wordpress
- `example.com/portal` -> Amplify project.

N.b I would like to use sub directories rather than a new subdomain, as I'm told that this helps with SEO as they will share the same page rank. The purpose of the blog is mostly for SEO and to attract people to the site.

**What I have considered:**

Set up a wordpress site, hosted on an Apache server (Maybe using AWS lightsail, one of the bitnami ones), and set up a reverse proxy on that Apache server to point at the amplify project.

**The problems I think this approach causes:**

1. The amplify project will be accessible from 2 URLs. The amplify app directly AND via `example.com/portal`; how do I stop this being available to the world via the amplify URL and only available through the reverse proxy (`example.com/portal`)?.
2. Should the apache server go down, the amplify app is then no longer accessible. The amplify project now depends on a single EC2 (or an auto scaling group potentially but this means adding a load balancer and much higher costs).
3. Amplify uses cloudfront as a CDN, by routing it all through a proxy we essentially lose the benefit that gives us.

**Other option: Put amplify at the top**

Have amplify use it's reverse proxy functionality to send requests to a wordpress page hosted elsewhere. This way if wordpress goes down, amplify lives on. My concerns here are:

1. Wordpress will be accessible from 2 URLs - How do I limit it to just allow the URL of the reverse proxy (example.com)?
2. I'll need to figure out how to get amplify to run on a URL that isn't the root of the domain, e.g "example.com/service" and will need to get the root of the domain to hit the reverse proxy.

**What would make an ideal answer for and hopefully others:**

- Which of these options you would pick (or a different one) that might help to minimise costs whilst keeping the same level of resiliency of AWS Amplify, and why? Please try to answer in a way that may be useful for a typical set up for others to follow.

Comment: Were you able to choose between options?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out. Basically AWS Amplify is just the tool. You would need to choose the framework that could be integrated with headless wordpress (via its api) easily.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/use-react-with-wordpress-to-create-headless-cms/